# How to programmatically open the Document Information Panel in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, office-2010

Could anyone show me an example on how to open the document information panel in word with vb.net. If you happen to wonder what document panel I refer to you can check screenshots at:

[How to Open the Document Information Panel in Microsoft Word 2010](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/07/how-to-open-the-document-information-panel-in-microsoft-word-2010/)

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim dialogBox As Word.Dialog = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs(Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSummaryInfo)
dialogBox.Show()
```

I've managed to open it up but it seems to be the wrong type of document panel.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

    oWord.DisplayDocumentInformationPanel = True
```